# Passwordless login for AFS

Tags: ssh, openafs, password-less

Is there a way to have passwordless login for a system running AFS? I tried a ssh key pair, but although I logged in with no issue, I did not get an AFS token. Every 24 hours, I need a new AFS token, which I could authenticate on the server via Kerberos and my password, making the passwordless login pointless.

Comment: With SSH you can login with a public/private key pair - no password.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Acquiring an AFS token for [AuriStorFS](https://www.auristor.com/filesystem/) or OpenAFS requires access to a Kerberos ticket granting ticket.  When an ssh session is established using

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# Specifies whether user authentication based on GSSAPI is allowed.
# The default is ``no''. Note that this option applies to protocol
# version 2 only.

GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
### Forward (delegate) credentials to the server. The default is
# ``no''. Note that this option applies to protocol version 2
# only.
```

a Kerberos ticket granting ticket can be forwarded to the target machine.  With a TGT in place AFS tokens can be obtained via [pam-afs-session](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-afs-session/).

I hope this helps.